# Adding Google Pointer to code

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using this google maps script code and it has no problems but I need to add a marker to it.

There's code that defined a marker but no marker seems to appear in the map.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(123456.-12345566);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng, 
map: map,
title:"Fast marker"
});

}
jQuery(document).ready(initialize);
</script>
```

How would I add a marker to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither coordinates (one for map, one for marker) are properly defined

[This page](http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/geocodeUK.html) will give you LatLng coordinates for the spot you click on the map to customize and fill in the values below.

```
//map center 
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12,-12); // <-- this one

var myOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// HERE ALSO
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12,-12); // <-- this one for the marker

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. It will add a pointer to a map.

Couple of things:

1. Do you have a Google API key? (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)
2. The coordinates you gave are no where. Try using -123456. 12345566 as a test.